# How do I get animation in OSG to playback?

Tags: c++, openscenegraph

I'm relatively new to c++ and open scene graph. I'm trying to make something that I have recorded in the application to playback, however I have an error that just won't budge - hoping it's something easy to fix.

```
if (!robotInputDeviceState->paused) {
            bodycb->setPause(false);

            robotInputDeviceState->outline->setWidth(0);
        }
        else {
            bodycb->setPause(true);

            findNode.getFirst()->setUpdateCallback(new updateRobotPosCallback(robotInputDeviceState, "BodyRotator"));
            robotInputDeviceState->bodyPath->clear();

        }
        return false;
        break;
```

The error code is in the screenshot below, and the red underline is on the bracket '(' after new updateRobotPosCallback and before the robotInputDeviceState.

Any ideas?[image: Error Code Details]

Comment: This is really a generic c++ compilation error, nothing related specifically to osg. Furthermore, without knowing the details of class you implemented it's impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment above by Jonathan - this is a fairly generic C++ compilation error, not really OSG-related. You are trying to use a version of the constructor that does not exist. Did you write the class updateRobotPosCallback? If so, does it have the 2-argument constructor in both the header file and the implementation file? If you didn't write it, where did you get it from, and are there more files that you are missing?